# JavaScript acrobatics: How to assign an object literal to an eval-uated property?

Tags: javascript

[Original code](https://github.com/jamiemthomas/jquery-datalink/blob/master/jquery.tmpl.datalink.js) from [JamieMThomas](https://github.com/jamiemthomas), a (really good guy who is trying to combine Microsoft JQuery Templates and Linking) :

```
mapping[binding.field] = {
    convert: function (value, source, target) {
        if (binding.converter && binding.converter.convert) {
            value = binding.converter.convert(value, source, target)
                if (value === undefined)
                    return;
        }
        $(target).attr(attrName, value);
    }
};
```

I am trying to hack it to allow `binding.field` to work with a string like `"LPC[0].itemid"` (literally a string).  I am using eval as a terrible choice, but it's the fastest thing I can do (and will rewrite it later).  I originally tried assigning the content to the eval('') itself, but it didn't allow me.

```
eval('(mapping.' + binding.field + ')') =
    { // rest is the same
    convert: function (value, source, target) {
        if (binding.converter && binding.converter.convert) {
            value = binding.converter.convert(value, source, target)
                if (value === undefined)
                    return;
        }
        $(target).attr(attrName, value);
    }
};
```

Obviously an invalid assignment on the left hand side.  How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the entire assignment in the `eval`:

```
eval('mapping.' + binding.field + ' = { ... }');
```

This would be a very large string containing the function definition
To make the string smaller, you can put the function in an external variable:

```
var converter = function (value, source, target) {
    if (binding.converter && binding.converter.convert) {
        value = binding.converter.convert(value, source, target)
            if (value === undefined)
                return;
    }
    $(target).attr(attrName, value);
};
eval('mapping.' + binding.field + ' = { convert: converter }');
```